# Custom View inside NSMenu Item in SWIFT

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsmenuitem

I wand to build a two line menu item in a taskbar Swift Application for MacOS, that behaves like a normal menu item, just with additional information. I managed to get the menu and the taskbar application going, but failed with the custom view inside the menu item.

Ideally I would like to use a SwiftUI View struct if this is at all possible in this case and avoid XIB files altogether.

**Update:** I tried NSHostingView for integration, but with the same result - the menu item would not display

*AppDelegate*

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
   self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:
        CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
   // set the menu and the task bar image
   self.statusBarItem.menu = TaskBarMenu()
   self.statusBarItem.button?.image = NSImage(named: "icon-normal")
}
```

*TaskbarMenu*

```
class TaskBarMenu: NSMenu {
  override init(title: String) {
    super.init(title: title)
    let testMenu = NSMenuItem()
    testMenu.view = TaskbarMenuView()

    items = [
       NSMenuItem(title:"Test Item", action: #selector(NSApplication.hide(_:)), keyEquivalent: "h"),
       NSMenuItem.separator(),
       testMenu
    ]
  }
  
  required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder : coder)
  }
}
```

*TaskbarMenuView*

```
class TaskbarMenuView: NSView {
    let nameTextField: NSTextField = {
        let textField = NSTextField()
        textField.stringValue = "Some custom name"
        return textField
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI macOS Commands (menu bar) and View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66557093/swiftui-macos-commands-menu-bar-and-view)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: You need to set the frame of the view, otherwise nothing is displayed.

[How to create status bar icon & menu with SwiftUI like in macos Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949572/how-to-create-status-bar-icon-menu-with-swiftui-like-in-macos-big-sur/65658093#65658093)